# Output html from ajax/jsonp request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to output html using an ajax request from a jsonp file . When using `console.log` I'm seeing the data looping fine, however when using a variable to grab the loop and output in html, I'm only seeing one result. What am I missing?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://sitedotcom/blog/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback",
    success: jsonpCallback
});

function jsonpCallback(data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(data[key]["title"] + ", " + data[key]["entry_id"]);
            rssData = '<h2>' + data[key]["title"] + "</h2><p>" + data[key]["blog_summary"] + "</p>";

        }
        $('#blog-content').html(rssData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$('#blog-content').html(rssData);` inside the loop....so only the last result will show since `html()` replaces all content.

Try using `append()` instead or concatenate `rssData` each iteration and set `html()` after loop completes

Comment: be careful though if the conditional is false first time `rssData` will be undefined...on any other iteration it is global and will duplicate prior content. Loop needs some cleaning up and don't use global

Answer (score 0):

It looks like rssData is out of scope when you are adding it to your #blog-content.  Also you are outputting different data when doing your console log and setting your rssData variable.

If you could provide the json layout and also the html layout you are trying to append to.